# Determinant reduction action. How to write it for a proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let
$$\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   { - 2} & 0 & 0 & {...} & 0  \\
   1 & { - 2} & 0 & {...} & 0  \\
   0 & 1 & { - 2} & {} & {}  \\
   {} & {} &  \ddots  & {} & {}  \\
   0 & {...} & 0 & 1 & { - 2}  \\
\end{array}} \right|
$$

For each row between $1$ and $n$, multiply the previous row by $1 \over 2$ and add it to the current row. Each step occur after the previous step was done. The goal is eliminating all the $1$-s. How do you write it mathematically in a short way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathcal{A}&=\{(i,j):i=j+1,i<n\}
\\ \hat{a}_{(i,j)} &= a_{(i,j)} - \frac{1}{2} a_{(i-1,j)} \forall (i,j)\in \mathcal{A}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Is the question to find the determinant? If so, there's a very quick solution.

Since this matrix $A$ is lower-triangular, $\det A$ is simply the product of its diagonal entries. That is,
$$
\det A=(-2)^n=(-1)^n\cdot 2^n
$$

Comment: Oh you right, Thanks.  
But since this was not my original question I'd accept @Inquest answer. Cheers